# Center Chart LineData After Hide Values MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have an `ArrayList<ILineDataSet>` that hide/show programatically on button click.

How can i have the remained values centered on chart?

```
private void toggleDataSetVisibility(String label) {
    chart.invalidate();
    for (int i = 0; i < allDataSets.size(); i++) {
        if (label != null) {
            if (label.equals(allDataSets.get(i).getLabel())) {
                if (allDataSets.get(i).isVisible()) {
                    allDataSets.get(i).setVisible(false);
                    allDataSets.get(i).setDrawValues(false);
                } else {
                    allDataSets.get(i).setVisible(true);
                    allDataSets.get(i).setDrawValues(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    chart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.animateX(1500);
}
```

EDIT:
The chart renders with all data

[image: All line datas]

After click

```
btnT1.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        toogleBtnPressed(v);
        toggleDataSetVisibility("T1");
    });



if (v.getId() == btnT1.getId()) {
        if (btnT1.isSelected()) {
            btnT1.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            btnT1.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
```

and after hide de linedata values:

[image: line data remain]

on this point i want to refresh te zoom and center vertically the line data that remains

Comment: Add current output in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i found is

Find visible datasets:

```
 List<ILineDataSet> sets = chart.getData().getDataSets();
    List<ILineDataSet> visibleSets = new ArrayList<>();
    ILineDataSet dataset = sets.get(datasetIdx);

    dataset.setVisible(!dataset.isVisible());

    /**Rápida checagem para ver o tamanho do array que irá ser sorteado
     * Possibilidade de conflito com temperatura "0.0" ao colocar um valor 'nulo (0.0)' no array.
     *
     * Resgata sets visiveis para evitar processamento desnecessário.
     * */

    for (ILineDataSet mySet : sets) {
        if (mySet.isVisible())
            visibleSets.add(mySet);
    }

    float[] myArrayMin = new float[visibleSets.size()];
    float[] myArrayMax = new float[visibleSets.size()];
```

After that run over they:

```
for (int i = 0; i < visibleSets.size(); i++) {
        LineDataSet set = (LineDataSet) visibleSets.get(i);
        float setYmin = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(set.getYMin()));
        float setYmax = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(set.getYMax()));
        myArrayMin[i] = setYmin;
        /**
         * O valor discrepante é feito para menos, mas quando ele existe ou há apenas ele
         * é necessário ajustá-lo para uma posição algumas casas maior [nesse caso 1015]
         * para que se obtenha uma boa visualização e ele não fique grudado no topo do chart
         * */
        if (setYmax == VALOR_DISCREPANTE)
            myArrayMax[i] = 1015;
        else
            myArrayMax[i] = setYmax;
    }
```

Sort and find highest and lowerest values:

```
Arrays.sort(myArrayMin);
Arrays.sort(myArrayMax);
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(myArrayMin[0]);
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(myArrayMax[myArrayMax.length - 1]);
```

Don't forget to refresh the chart:

```
 chart.invalidate();
 chart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
 chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
 chart.animateX(1500);
```